# Fetch rows with maximum length of string in another column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have following table in postgres11

```
trial_id    name_split  drug_name_who
NCT01877395 imovax® rabies  imovax
NCT01877395 imovax® rabies  imovax rabies
NCT01877395 imovax® rabies  rabies
NCT01877395 imovax® rabies  rabies imovax
NCT00000374     olanzapine      olanzapine                  
NCT00000390     imipramine hydrochloride    imipramine hydrochloride    
NCT00000390     imipramine hydrochloride    imipramine
```

I would like to fetch rows with maximum length values per 'trial_id name_split'.

I tried following query:

```
with x as (

        SELECT distinct on (trial_id,name_split) *
        FROM table
        WHERE 
            regexp_replace(name_split, '[^\w]', '#', 'g') ~* ('\y'||regexp_replace(drug_name_who, '[^\w]', '#', 'g')||'\y')
            and (length(drug_name_who) > 2)
            or (drug_name_who is null)
            ORDER  BY trial_id, name_split, length(drug_name_who) DESC NULLS LAST)
            
select * from x;
```

The query can correctly fetch rows where length of 'drug_name_who' per trial_id is not equal but when length of 'drug_name_who' per trial_id is equal, the query selects only one row (for example: NCT01877395, following row is missing: NCT01877395  imovax® rabies  imovax)

The desired output is:

```
trial_id    name_split  drug_name_who
NCT01877395 imovax® rabies  imovax
NCT01877395 imovax® rabies  rabies
NCT00000374     olanzapine      olanzapine                  
NCT00000390     imipramine hydrochloride    imipramine hydrochloride
```

Any help here is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`distinct on` always return only one row per group - if the `order by` clause is not deterministic, then you get a random row out of the ties.

If you want to allow ties, then you can use `rank()` and a subquery instead:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        rank() over(
            partition by trial_id, name_split 
            order by length(drug_name_who) desc
        ) rn
    from mytable t
    where ...
) t
where rn = 1
```